# Transmission won't download torrents to NTFS HDD. Permission denied"

Tags: mount, ntfs, transmission

I believe I have a permissions issue getting transmission-gtk to download to my NTFS drive. I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. I've edited the `/etc/fstab` file to automount my NTFS drive with the following parameters:

```
UUID=8016D86516D85DAA /media/4TB ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,auto,umask=000 0 0
```

I've tried a range of different permission settings, using fmask and dmask values. I tried chown'ing and chmod'ing the folders as well, but even though they have read write execute permission, the file download still fails due to permission denied - I did read that this was due to chown'ing not working on NTFS drives... but I digress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem but without success. I'm using the same FSTAB settings. Try `sudo umount /media/4TB` and then `sudo mount -a`.

Comment: It turns out that Transmission wasn't even the issue. The problem seems to be permission settings for couchpotato instead. Sonarr is retrieving and downloading/renaming just fine (on the NTFS drive). Couchpotato is now downloading as I've just switched to using the /home directory but won't move/rename the files it downloads to an alternative directory (again on /home)

Comment: Addition: This was only achieved as I set permissions for directories to allow users/groups/others full rw access. I'd rather elevate CP's permissions than allow anything the access... Unfortunately I can't find what user/group CP is operating as